# python selenium unable to locate element after refresh

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap a webpage using python and selenium. When I first tried, I was able to find the element and it worked. When I refreshed the page and tried to run it again it was throwing an error that the element is unable to locate although the element is still visible. My code so far:
`target_xpath = "//span[contains(text(), 'IBM')]" WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, target_xpath)))`

The webpage shows the following when I inspect (the same before and after refreshing):

```
<span class="className" aria-hidden="true">
              IBM
            </span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">
              Filter by IBM
            </span>
```

Comment: can you share a link to that page and more your code?

Comment: How did you refresh. I want to say unless you use the WebDriver to refresh (it has a refresh method to call) then you break the connection if you did a manual refresh.